# Edit a record in MVC multi layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, edit, layer, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a project with 8 layers
I want to edit a record ; for example:
In repository layer:
1:in IRepository:
  IEnumerable GetArea(int id);

```
    void Edit(CRM_Area crm);
```

2: in repository:

```
public IEnumerable<CRM_Area> GetArea(int ID)
        {
           return _db.CrmAreas.Where(x=>x.ID==ID);
        }

        public void Edit(CRM_Area crmArea)
        {
            _db.Entry(crmArea).State=EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

and in services layer:
1:in Iservices:

```
void Delete(int ID);
        IEnumerable<_CRM_AreaList> GetArea(int ID);  

        void Edit(_CRM_AreaEdit crmArea);
```

2: in Services:

```
public IEnumerable<_CRM_AreaList> GetArea(int ID)
       {
           return _areaRepository.GetArea(ID).Select(Mapper.Map<CRM_Area, _CRM_AreaList>);
       }


           public void Edit(_CRM_AreaEdit crmAreaEdit)
           {
               var editArea = Mapper.Map<_CRM_AreaEdit, CRM_Area>(crmAreaEdit);
               _areaRepository.Edit(editArea);

           }
```

and in web layer in controller:

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
        {

```
        return View(_areaServices.GetArea(ID));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(_CRM_AreaEdit crmAreaEdit)
    {
        _areaServices.Edit(crmAreaEdit);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

But it doesn't work.  Please help me - How can I edit and where is my mistake?
When I click on edit, the model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[CRM.Web.Models.CRM_Area,CRM.Web.ViewModel.Area._CRM_AreaList]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CRM.Web.ViewModel.Area._CRM_AreaEdit'.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository try to save the changes.
Always keep in mind, you need to save the changes after you edit it.

```
public void Edit(CRM_Area crmArea)
{
    _db.Entry(crmArea).State=EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my error is not pass:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[CRM.Web.Models.CRM_Area,CRM.Web.ViewModel.Area._CRM_AreaList]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CRM.Web.ViewModel.Area._CRM_AreaEdit'.